# How can I show gridlines only of the even value ones withchartjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am trying chartjs for first time,I would like to get the gridlines to be thicker and grey on even numbers, and also that the odd numbers gridlines are not shown so only 20, 40, 60... will be shown on the grindlines with a thicker grey line, if this makes sense, this is what I haave at the moment, I have tried to call a  callback funciton on the gridlines option what does not work or I am using it wrong:

```
    buildChart = () => {
    const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");

    myLineChart = new Chart(myChartRef, {
      type: "radar",
      data: {
        labels: ["Fifa20", "CS:GO", "Dota 2", "LOL", "Overwatch", "Fortnite"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Games",
            data: [40, 45, 53, 45, 100, 13],
            backgroundColor: [
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent"
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)"
            ],
            borderWidth: 5,
            pointBorderWidth: 0,
            pointBorderColor: "transparent"
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,

        scale: {
          ticks: {
            display: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            fontSize: 7,
            // stepSize: 10,
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              switch (value) {
                case 20:
                  return value;
                  break;
                case 40:
                  return value;
                  break;
                case 60:
                  return value;
                  break;
                case 80:
                  return value;
                  break;
                case 100:
                  return value;
                  break;
                default:
                  return "";
              }
            }
          },
          angleLines: {
            display: true
          },
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
            color: "#cac7c7"
          },
          pointLabels: {
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold"
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
        <canvas id="myChart" ref={this.chartRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to only show gridlines for 20, 40, 60 and so on, you can define `scale.ticks.stepSize: 20`. To make the gridlines thicker, define `scale.gridLines.lineWidth: 5` for example.

Please have a look at the following runnable code snippet.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
      type: "radar",
      data: {
        labels: ["Fifa20", "CS:GO", "Dota 2", "LOL", "Overwatch", "Fortnite"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Games",
            data: [40, 45, 53, 45, 100, 13],
            backgroundColor: [
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent"
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)"
            ],
            borderWidth: 5,
            pointBorderWidth: 0,
            pointBorderColor: "transparent"
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scale: {
          ticks: {
            display: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            stepSize: 20,
            fontSize: 7,
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              switch (value) {
                case 20:
                  return value;
                  break;
                case 40:
                  return value;
                  break;
                case 60:
                  return value;
                  break;
                case 80:
                  return value;
                  break;
                case 100:
                  return value;
                  break;
                default:
                  return "";
              }
            }
          },
          angleLines: {
            display: true
          },
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
            lineWidth: 5,
            color: "#cac7c7"
          },
          pointLabels: {
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold"
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

```css
canvas {
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```